# Swipe up and down to overlay two widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter

[image]

I'm having 2 `widget A` and `B` with position like photo above.
How can I move `widget B` overlay `widget A` when touch or swipe-up from `widget B` and back when swipe-down?

Answer (score 1):

Make a `GestureDetector` and give it a `stack` as a child. Create a variable in your class thats called `y` or whatever name you want.
In your stack make 2 `positioned` widgets.

```
positioned(
    top: 0
    left: 0
),
positioned(
    top: y
    left: 0
)
```

make your two Widgets `A` and `B` childs of the positioned. Widget B has to be in the second positioned for it to overlay the first.

Make an `AnimationController` in your class and set its start value to 0 and its end value to the y. Use the `onVerticalDragDown`method of the `GestureDetector` to detect vertical swipes and check if it was from top to bottom or from bottom to top. If it was from bottom to top call `animationController.reverse();`, if it was from top to bottom call `animationController.forward();`. In the animationController Listener call `setState((){y = animationController.value})`. If you dont want it to be animated just set `y` to the values that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Learn about => https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

> A widget that positions its children relative to the edges of its box.
>
> This class is useful if you want to overlap several children in a
> simple way, for example having some text and an image, overlaid with a
> gradient and a button attached to the bottom.